# I am trying to create a ASR model, and I'm running into a value error

Tags: tensorflow, automatic-speech-recognition

Here is the code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17bOorPg5izV2PEoX6O19NtFM1clrhF6T?usp=sharing
I'm creating an ASR model, and I'm running into the following error:
slice index 1 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
I'm not really sure how to fix this error.
The model is based of of:
https://keras.io/examples/audio/ctc_asr/ , but I did the preprocessing differently.